# MySQL statement that groups results, but also returns the lowest and the highest value of another column from within the group

Tags: mysql

Ok, so this is my hypothetical table:

```
Id     Page       Timestamp     Etc

 1        1      2009-10-10     ...
 2        1      2009-10-13     ...
 3        1      2009-10-14     ...
 4        1      2009-10-20     ...
 5        2      2009-10-24     ...
 6        2      2009-10-27     ...
 7        2      2009-11-06     ...
 8        3      2009-11-06     ...
 9        4      2009-11-07     ...
10        4      2009-11-20     ...
11        4      2009-11-21     ...
```

And what I need is a query that in each row returns the page number...

```
SELECT * FROM `hypothetical_table` WHERE `Visible` = 1 AND `foo` = 'blargh' GROUP BY `Page` HAVING COUNT(`Page`) >= 1 ORDER BY `Page` ASC
```

... but *also returns the lowest and the highest value from the Timestamp column within the group.* So that on the flipside I can output something like:

• **Page 1** (from October 10th 2009 to October 20th 2009)
• **Page 2** (from October 24th 2009 to November 6th 2009)
• **Page 3** (November 6th 2009)
• **Page 4** (from November 7th 2009 to November 21th 2009)

Is this even doable with straight MySQL?

Comment: I hate MySQL `GROUP BY` - What does it return for `Etc` when you group by `Page` is it undefined?

Comment: My experience is that it returns the representative row's values; you can `ORDER BY` something to force it to return a particular row there.

Comment: So what happens if you use `MAX` and `MIN` - Which row's value do you get for the other columns?

Comment: Good question. Lemme try it somewhere (this particular situation doesn't have a ready db full of dummy values to test, so I will have to try it elsewhere). BRB

Comment: I it is pulling up the lower ID values and/or things appearing earlier in the internal hierarchy. It does indeed go by whatever it is `ORDERed BY` before it decides to just plugs in whatever value it wants. That part doesn't seem to be affected by the MIN/MAX at all. There may be a proper way to pull up a specific collection of values in the continuation as well, but I am not the person to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT `Page`, MIN(`Timestamp`) as StartDate, MAX(`Timestamp`) as EndDate
    FROM `hypothetical_table` 
    WHERE `Visible` = 1 
        AND `foo` = 'blargh' 
    GROUP BY `Page` 
    HAVING COUNT(`Page`) >= 1 
    ORDER BY `Page` ASC
```

Comment: +1 The original query has `*` though which is valid in MySQL but I'm not sure what the result is.

Comment: @Martin: I also took into account the output of his expected results, which seems to show just those 3 columns.

Comment: That is a lot cleaner solution than I thought possible. It only makes sense within the `GROUP BY` context, correct?

Comment: @Hoatzin: Yes, you need the `GROUP BY` for the aggregate `MIN` and `MAX` functions to apply to each page.