# How can I get the max value within a max value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a schema like the following

```
id (INT)
Cycle_Number (INT)
Cycle_Day (INT)
Date (date)
```

...other columns irrelevant to the question...

How can I get the row that has the max Cycle_Day within the max Cycle_Number

For example, say I have the following data

```
ID Cycle_Number Cycle_Day Date
1  1            1         2011-12-01
2  1            2         2011-12-02
3  2            1         2011-12-03
4  2            2         2011-12-04
5  2            3         2011-12-05
6  2            4         2011-12-06
7  3            1         2011-12-07
8  3            2         2011-12-08
9  3            3         2011-12-09
```

The query would return row 9. (It has the highest Cycle_Day within the highest Cycle_Number)

Thanks

Comment: what if the row with the highest cycle number does not have the highest cycle day?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL statement that groups results, but also returns the lowest and the highest value of another column from within the group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681918/mysql-statement-that-groups-results-but-also-returns-the-lowest-and-the-highest)

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, that doesn't matter. I have included a pair with cycle_Number = 2, Cycle_Day = 4... I still want row 9. I need the highest Cycle_Day within the highest Cycle_Number

Comment: Ah I misunderstood... removing my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one is compatible MySql 5.5 with no joint tables

```
SELECT id
FROM cycles
ORDER BY Cycle_Number DESC , Cycle_Day DESC
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Regards

Comment: Lol... I've just realised how I overdid my answer and came back to edit it to a variant of yours. +1 P.S. `LIMIT 1` should be enough

Comment: You shouldn't forget to add indexes on columns used in the ORDER BY ; instead all results would be loaded before the LIMIT command.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL query should provide the max value you want.

```
SELECT ID, Cycle_Number, Cycle_Day, Date
FROM  yourTable AS t
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(Cycle_Number) AS Cycle_Number FROM yourTable
) AS sq USING (Cycle_Number)
ORDER BY Cycle_Day DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I get an error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias